# How to modify parameters alignment in SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have one specific requirement wherein I need to change the alignment and width of parameters controls on SSRS 2016 (I'm using Visual Studio 2017).

Now I know for a fact that Microsoft has added some customization feature starting SSRS 2016, in terms of parameters arrangement into a matrix, but that seems to be it.

Is there any way to achieve the below mentioned alignment/customization of parameters controls/dropdowns.

Would appreciate any pointers here.

[image]

Comment: I do not believe you can manually resize your parameters like you have specified.. Yes.. 2016 allows for playing with parameter placement.. but that's as good as it gets.. unfortunately!

Comment: Yes, I kind of concluded on the same. Thanks!